# How to define the interaction between two coupling waves in a silicon photonic directional coupler?

Tags: photonics

How can one define the interaction between two waves in a directional coupler?
For instance, given the following structure

[image: Directional coupler]

it is straightforward to calculate the power ratio for one input to the left regarding the coupler length L:
$P_{ratio}(L) = P_{in}*sin^2{\frac{\pi*\Delta n}{\lambda}*L}$

but this equation only gives the ratio when there is no interaction between waves. Is it possible to obtain something similar when two waves are inserted simultaneously on each one of the inputs to the left?

Comment: Are the two waves coherent with each other or not? Are the power levels low enough to neglect nonlinear behavior?

Comment: the waves can be at any phase (0 to 2$\pi$). for now I do not care about non linear behaviour.

Comment: So they're out of phase, but coherent?  Or they're not coherent (not exactly the same frequency)?

Comment: Yes, they are coherent. Not that it would make a difference, but my band is limited to C-band only.

Answer (score 0):

If you had two incoherent sources illuminating the two input arms of the coupler, the outputs would simply be the sum of the outputs due to the two sources.

But since you have two coherent sources, there can be interference (either constructive or destructive) between the signals from the two sources at the two output ports.

To find the output in this case, you'll have to get the output electric field rather than just the power, as a function of the input field. Then you'll be able to sum the output field due to the two inputs and get the total field at the output.

As the relative phase of the two sources sweeps through [0, $2\pi] you'll see the output at one of the two output ports sweep between maximum constructive interference and maximum destructive interference. The phase difference giving maximum constructive interference will depend on the exact geometry of the device, as will the extinction ratio at the point of destructive interference.

The phase difference that gives destructive interference at one output port will give constructive interference at the other port, and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the answer! so, if the are incoherent, I can simply consider each case as an individual case and rely in the same equation? for the coherent ones, is it safe to make a simple assumption, such as define an "amount" of interference on the waves, in order to define the final signal? for instance, for $\pi$, the waves cancel each other, so no light is seem in the output. for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ there is destructive interference, and half the light will be seem in the output.. and so on.